# WooCommerce product methods return empty values in a custom Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, product

I am facing an issue with retrieving values for custom fields in WooCommerce while developing a WordPress plugin. Specifically, I'm trying to obtain values for the variables $availability and $stock_quantity, but they do not seem to return any data.

```php
while( $events->have_posts() ) {
    $events->the_post();
    $startDate = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), apply_filters( 'piecal_start_date_meta_key', '_piecal_start_date' ) );
    $endDate = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), apply_filters( 'piecal_end_date_meta_key', '_piecal_end_date' ) );
    $postType = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() );
    $allday = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_piecal_is_allday') ? get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_piecal_is_allday', true) : "false";
    $acfFieldValue = get_field('kurscode', get_the_ID());
    $acfFieldValue2 = get_field('dauer', get_the_ID());
    $acfFieldValue3 = get_field('preis_pro_tag_pro_person', get_the_ID());
    $product_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'product_id', true);
    $termine = get_field('termine', get_the_ID());
    $availability = '';
    $stock_quantity = '';

    if ($product_id && function_exists('wc_get_product')) 
    {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $availability = $product->get_stock_status();
        $stock_quantity= $product->get_stock_quantity();
    }
    
    if ($acfFieldValue2 == 1) 
    {
        $dauer_text = 'Tag';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $dauer_text = 'Tagen';
    }
    
    $event = [
        'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID()),
        "title" => html_entity_decode(get_the_title()),
        "start" => $startDate[0],
        "end" => $endDate[0] ?? null,
        "details" => html_entity_decode(get_the_excerpt()),
        "permalink" => get_permalink(),
        "postType" => $postType->labels->singular_name ?? null,
        "kurscode" => $acfFieldValue,
        "dauer" => $acfFieldValue2. ' '. $dauer_text,
        "preis_pro_tag_pro_person" => $acfFieldValue3,
        'product_availability' => $availability,
        'stock'=> $stock_quantity,
    ];
}
```

Comment: With the provided code, the very few details and explanations, it is not possible to guess by magic what the problem could be. You should try to replace `if ($product_id && function_exists('wc_get_product')){` with `if (get_post_type($product_id) === 'product' && function_exists('wc_get_product')){` and add an `} else {` that throw an error or write some info to the error.log.

Comment: Why not using Woo query ? Here is more information provided by Woo team - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query . Also dont understand one time you are using get_the_ID() other times $product_id. You should check $product = wc_get_product($product_id); if its a product then get the data you need from it.